# Why do I need package line in my class file while coding java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

So my first time using Eclipse doing an elementary program. I noticed that in Eclipse, you cannot compile a single class file. Rather you need to create a project on top of that. So I did create a project and created a class under the project. I noticed the code

package PackageName;

at the top of the class file. And if I delete the file and run the file, it gives me errors. May anyone answer me why is this happening? Thanks.

My code:

```
public class CSYes {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Computer Science, Yes!!!!");
        System.out.println("=========================");
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at proj1.CSYes.main(CSYes.java:3)
```

However, If I have

```
package proj1;

    public class CSYes {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Computer Science, Yes!!!!");
            System.out.println("=========================");
        }
    }
```

It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you post your code and error messages

Comment: Instead of jumping to eclipse, practise from command line.

Comment: It's simply good form to have packages for most "real code".  Eclipse encourages that style, and makes it easy to create and use packages.  If you really want to avoid using a package, then make sure your .java source file is in the *root* level of your project.  Your error is probably because the  file is in a package subdirectory in the project, but you're not declaring the corresponding package in your .java source code.

Comment: @paulsm4 But then if I am a teacher and am receiving the code with the first line specifing package name, do I need to create a package with the name to run this code? Or there is some quicker way of running it if all I am reeiving is the .java code.

Comment: @Suresh Atta - I used to feel that way (and I still use command line tools whenever convenient).  But it's *equally* important to learn one or more IDEs.

Comment: If you were a teacher, you'd ask the students to use Eclipse's "export as archive" feature, then use Eclipse's "import archive" feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The Eclipse IDE encourages you to use packages.  In general, it's a good idea.  I'd encourage you to use packages, too.
2. It is NOT, however, a requirement.  It sounds like you inadverantly created a "proj1" package when you created the project and/or .java class.  Whoops!
3. To fix the problem, simply a) delete the package reference in your .java source, then b) move the .java file *OUT* of "/src/proj1" and put in directly under "/src" (the "default package").

... OR, EASIER ...

4. Delete the entire source (both CSYes.java and proj1)
5. File > New > Java Class > Name= CSYes; leave package "blank" (i.e. "default package")
6. Copy/paste your code back into CSYes.
7. Voila!  Done :)